WhatsApp Business API Webhook doesn't work even though subscribed properly
I'm having a few issues with WhatsApp business API webhook. I've subscribed to the webhook under WhatsApp business account and turned on the messages event as well, but I don't get any notifications when the user sends a message to the business number.
I can say for sure that my server is setup properly to receive calls as the test webhook calls are reaching my server, but nothing when the user sends a message to the associated business number.
I have checked my access token as well for anything and it seems to have the proper permissions associated with in the access token debugger including whatsapp_business_management and whatsapp_business_messaging
Has anyone faced this before?
I have checked my access token as well for anything and it seems to have the proper permissions associated with in the access token debugger including whatsapp_business_management and whatsapp_business_messaging

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
